# How do I control the number of tick marks/y-axis values on one of the plots in ggarrange?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm sorry I can't provide the data for my graphs. My root problem is that I can't figure out how to control the values printed on the y-axis if you use the following ggarrange syntax to combine 2 plots:

```
  gg.combined <- ggarrange(plot1, plot2, ncol = 1, nrow = 2, align = "v", heights = c(3, 1))
```

When `plot2` is rendered it has a lot of tick marks on the y-axis which is fine for the plot itself. In the above `ggarrange` command I shrink `plot2` by 1/3 so the tick marks clump up. How do I re-scale the y-axis in `plot2` so the tick marks don't clump up in `gg.combined`? or maybe I need to re-scale in `gg.combined`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could specify the ticks manually and increase the space between ticks when needed.

e.g

```
data(iris)
g1 <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Length, col = Species)) + geom_point()
g2 <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = Petal.Length, col = Species)) + geom_point()

btw_tick <- 1 # space between 2 ticks
ggarrange(g1 + scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(1,8, btw_tick)), 
          g2 + scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(1,8, btw_tick * 3)), 
          ncol = 1, nrow = 2, align = "v", heights = c(3, 1))
```

[image]

Comment: It is surprising that there is no option in ggarrange to pretty-print the y-axis labels or some transformation that can be applied to the result of it...

Comment: Well to be fair, plots with very broad Y-axes probably shouldn't be "squished" to the point that the ticks overlap ;-)

Comment: ended up implementing a solution using: `breaks <- c((plot2.y.max - plot2.y.min) / 4 + plot2.y.min, plot2.y.max - (plot2.y.max - plot2.y.min) / 4)`. This worked! Thank you for the example!

Answer (score 1):

I think `scale_y_` might be helpful :

```
df <- mtcars
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)
plot1 <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = hp, y = wt)) +
  geom_line() 

plot2 <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = mpg, y=disp)) +
  geom_point() + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(200, 400))

gg.combined <- ggarrange(plot1, plot2, ncol = 1, nrow = 2, align = "v", heights = c(3, 1))

gg.combined
```

[image: image desc]